# ParametricPlot and ParametricPlot3D crash with subscript notation

Tags: plotting, bugs, crash, subscript

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.2 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

In all previous versions of Mathematica, the following works perfectly well:

```
ParametricPlot[{Subscript[x,1] + Subscript[x,2], Subscript[x,1] - Subscript[x,2]}, 
  {Subscript[x,1], 0, 1}, {Subscript[x,2], 0, 1}]
```

or...

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Subscript[x,1] + Subscript[x,2], Subscript[x,1] - Subscript[x,2], 0}, 
  {Subscript[x, 1], 0, 1}, {Subscript[x, 2], 0, 1}]
```

But as of v11.0, both `ParametricPlot` and `ParametricPlot3D` will cause the kernel to crash when using subscripted variables. This problem seems to exist at least on both Mac and Windows. I am not sure if it affects other plotting functions: certainly, Plot3D is working fine :)

One temporary fix is to remove the subscript notation as per:

```
ParametricPlot[ {x1 + x2, x1 - x2}, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[ {x1 + x2, x1 - x2, 0}, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]
```

... which seems to be a 'workaround'.

Is anyone aware of other plotting functions not working correctly with `Subscript`s etc?  The problem appears to be new to version v11.0.

Update: 9 July 2017 (rewards!)

[image]

Comment: I get the same thing with 11.1.1 on Mac.  Interesting, I didn't know that `ParametricPlot` could use two independent variables!

Comment: I can't speak to why it worked before and doesn't now, but "Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code" is usually given as general advice here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Comment: Please use the standard bug header, and do warn people about the kernel crash.   I know you originally wrote that it fails in 11.1 and works in all previous versions, but I see the crash in 11.0 too, every time, so I changed this ...

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in the latest version - `13.2.0`

The code:

```
ParametricPlot[{Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2], 
  Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 2]}, {Subscript[x, 1], 0, 
  1}, {Subscript[x, 2], 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[{Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2], 
  Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 2], 0}, {Subscript[x, 1], 0, 
  1}, {Subscript[x, 2], 0, 1}]
```

> [image: p1]

> [image: Blockquote]

and a screenshot

> [image: screen]